# Glassfish JavaEE MySQL transaction locked and block all

Tags: mysql, transactions, glassfish

I have trouble with my application developped in JAVA EE 8 and Glassifish... Since a couple of week, Glassfish send transaction to MySQL and sometimes (impossible to reproduce manually or to understand the log to know what's the problem) a transaction stay running and block the full application.

After I have this error :

```
[2020-11-17T14:55:45.388+0100] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] []
[org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] [tid: _ThreadID=177 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(11)] [timeMillis: 1605621345388] [levelValue: 800] [[
HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement]]

[2020-11-17T14:55:45.388+0100] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] [tid: _ThreadID=177 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(11)] [timeMillis: 1605621345388] [levelValue: 800] [[
HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement]]

javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.useClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:359)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.preInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:253)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4494)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1936)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy404.ajout(Unknown Source)
at ch.BusinessService.TypeReservationPersonneManager.ajout(TypeReservationPersonneManager.java:63)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1470.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4756)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4728)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4716)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy275.ajout(Unknown Source)
at service.TypeReservationPersonneFacadeREST.ajoutAbo(TypeReservationPersonneFacadeREST.java:32)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1388.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4756)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4728)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4716)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy322.ajoutAbo(Unknown Source)
at service.__EJB31_Generated__TypeReservationPersonneFacadeREST__Intf____Bean__.ajoutAbo(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1388.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:480)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-11-17T14:55:45.389+0100] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-EJB-00056] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=177 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(11)] [timeMillis: 1605621345389] [levelValue: 900] [[
  A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB TypeReservationPersonneManager, method: public void ch.BusinessService.TypeReservationPersonneManager.ajout(int,int,int,int)]]
```

and when I do `SHOW PROCESSLIST`in MySQL, I see that all process are blocked because of the transaction and impossible to go further with the application.

**EDIT : **

I success to reproduce the trouble on the live server and I did `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`and this is the result

```
=====================================
2020-11-17 21:15:31 7f2d3b5e9700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 47 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 4188 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 3105 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 7293
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 21306
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 121420
Mutex spin waits 531864, rounds 953991, OS waits 11585
RW-shared spins 233875, rounds 1314695, OS waits 6340
RW-excl spins 85836, rounds 717366, OS waits 3022
Spin rounds per wait: 1.79 mutex, 5.62 RW-shared, 8.36 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 744371550
Purge done for trx's n:o < 744371544 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 744347278, not started
MySQL thread id 13657, OS thread handle 0x7f2d3b508700, query id 2192631 localhost 127.0.0.1 userres 
---TRANSACTION 744370010, not started
MySQL thread id 13656, OS thread handle 0x7f2d4d7fe700, query id 2295945 localhost 127.0.0.1 userres 
---TRANSACTION 744358938, not started
MySQL thread id 10249, OS thread handle 0x7f2d3b5e9700, query id 2306949 213.55.220.67 userres init
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 744318375, not started
MySQL thread id 9232, OS thread handle 0x7f2d32959700, query id 2056900 localhost postfix_policyd 
---TRANSACTION 744308703, not started
MySQL thread id 2114, OS thread handle 0x7f2d329a4700, query id 2029930 localhost postfix_policyd 
---TRANSACTION 744271350, not started
MySQL thread id 1805, OS thread handle 0x7f2d3290e700, query id 1891670 localhost postfix_policyd 
---TRANSACTION 744371401, not started
MySQL thread id 15, OS thread handle 0x7f2d53886700, query id 2306184 localhost 127.0.0.1 userres 
---TRANSACTION 744297521, not started
MySQL thread id 352, OS thread handle 0x7f2d5391c700, query id 1984473 localhost postfix_policyd 
---TRANSACTION 744371549, not started
MySQL thread id 13, OS thread handle 0x7f2d4d7b3700, query id 2306718 localhost 127.0.0.1 userres 
---TRANSACTION 743779843, not started
MySQL thread id 1, OS thread handle 0x7f2d53967700, query id 0 Waiting for requests
---TRANSACTION 744370160, ACTIVE 20 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 14084, OS thread handle 0x7f2d3b472700, query id 2296778 localhost MY_DB Sending data
DELETE FROM numeroreservation WHERE numero IN (SELECT numero FROM (SELECT numero FROM numeroreservation ORDER BY numero DESC LIMIT 5, 99999) as x)
Trx #rec lock waits 1 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 20 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 83 page no 3 n bits 776 index `PRIMARY` of table `MY_DB`.`numeroreservation` trx table locks 1 total table locks 4  trx id 744370160 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 20 wait time before grant 0 
------------------
---TRANSACTION 744369665, ACTIVE 24 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 14, OS thread handle 0x7f2d4e865700, query id 2294750 localhost 127.0.0.1 userres update
INSERT INTO numeroreservation (numero) VALUES(2410411)
Trx #rec lock waits 1 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 24 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 83 page no 3 n bits 776 index `PRIMARY` of table `MY_DB`.`numeroreservation` trx table locks 1 total table locks 4  trx id 744369665 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 24 wait time before grant 0 
------------------
---TRANSACTION 744367990, ACTIVE 44 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 12, OS thread handle 0x7f2d4e8b0700, query id 2280810 localhost 127.0.0.1 userres update
INSERT INTO numeroreservation (numero) VALUES(2410411)
Trx #rec lock waits 4 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 1 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 44 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 83 page no 3 n bits 776 index `PRIMARY` of table `MY_DB`.`numeroreservation` trx table locks 1 total table locks 4  trx id 744367990 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 44 wait time before grant 0 
------------------
---TRANSACTION 744367985, ACTIVE 45 sec
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 149
MySQL thread id 11, OS thread handle 0x7f2d5383b700, query id 2306948 localhost 127.0.0.1 userres 
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
3492514 OS file reads, 126847 OS file writes, 42386 OS fsyncs
506.41 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 21.91 writes/s, 8.60 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 2996, seg size 2998, 2503 merges
merged operations:
 insert 5013, delete mark 7772, delete 1996
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
32455.37 hash searches/s, 13179.55 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 88167956003
Log flushed up to   88167956003
Pages flushed up to 88167883665
Last checkpoint at  88167883665
Max checkpoint age    80826164
Checkpoint age target 78300347
Modified age          72338
Checkpoint age        72338
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
28468 log i/o's done, 5.23 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 140574720; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 2112
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 13473376    (2213368 + 11260008)
    Page hash           139112 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    1485776     (554768 + 931008)
    File system         1577960     (812272 + 765688)
    Lock system         341208  (332872 + 8336)
    Recovery system     0   (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 931008
Buffer pool size        8191
Buffer pool size, bytes 134201344
Free buffers            1024
Database pages          6480
Old database pages      2372
Modified db pages       206
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 2.745
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 805084, not young 461986343
108.36 youngs/s, 87546.33 non-youngs/s
Pages read 3492228, created 1081, written 92653
506.41 reads/s, 0.19 creates/s, 15.36 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 996 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 564 / 1000
Pages read ahead 232.34/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 6480, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[13990]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
4 RW transactions active inside InnoDB
0 RO transactions active inside InnoDB
4 out of 1000 descriptors used
Main thread process no. 32076, id 139831933908736, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 2389, updated 170325, deleted 853, read 678563355
3.30 inserts/s, 9.64 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 72578.35 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

So this is happening when I add a lot of thing to do in the same place.. But it's never has trouble until a couple of days.. why now this is blocking it ?

My question is :

- Why I have it now when my application has 10 years without this problem
- how to solve it ? because this is in production and this is very a big problem yet

Comment: Unfortunately, your stack trace does not show anything interesting. Taken at its word, it says it can not prepare a statement, but does not say why. Nothing here indicates it's holding a transaction. A held transaction tends to manifest as a socket call to the DB, if the DB is the source of the block, a socket call to an outside service, if it's the cause of the block, or an internal lock of somekind if the transaction is waiting on something internally. But nothing like that is indicated here. I would suggest getting a thread dump of the server when this happens next time.

Comment: Ok thank you.. How can I do a thread dump ?

Comment: Is a solution to disabled transaction until it's working again ?

Comment: Thread dump: `jstack <PID>`

Comment: There are several resources on getting a thread dump, as it can be platform dependent, so I'll defer to you to hunt that down. I don't suggest disabling the transaction. If you have a stuck transaction, the thing to do is to run the thread dump more than once, and then compare them to see what's running in common across them (i.e. this is still running afte 1 or 2 minutes). You'll need intimate knowledge of the application to make sense of the stack traces, but anything running for more than a minute deserves study.

Comment: My problem is that the trouble are in production version and I need to restart mysql to have it working again. I don't have time to study why this is blocking. Is there a way to unlock automatically and quickly when thread are blocked for any reason ?

Comment: @Chatis I'm not a MySQL person, but that looks to me that those transactions are all waiting on a lock (of some kind) on the 'numeroreservation' table. What it does not show is the current, pending locks. Again, typically, this happens because some Java code has made a change to the DB and is then off doing something else, vs some long transaction running within the DB. Simply, a routine in the server grabbed a lock, and is now busy doing something else. Perhaps it grabbed the lock and is now making an external web service call to a machine that is not responding.

Comment: @Chatis this is why it's important to get the thread dump to gain insight in to what your application server is doing when these happen. On my production systems, I have a thread dump run every 5 minutes, day in day out, as they can be good for post mortem analysis when Weird Stuff happens. 5m may be too coarse for you application, so perhaps run one every minute and wait for this to happen again. Then you can go back in time seeing the state of your server up until you reach your event.

Comment: @Chatis as for MySQL, I can't say. If you can find the process that's holding the lock against the others and somehow terminate that, that would be a better solution than kicking the entire DB server. But I don't know MySQL well enough to offer guidance on how to do that. I would consider searching for "what's holding the lock in MySQL" and "how to terminate a connection in MySQL".